# How can I delete a picture from my Photos app on iPad?

Tags: ipad

So far I can only delete pictures from iPhoto.

How can I delete a picture from my Photos app on iPad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the "Photos" view and press the Sharing button:

[image]

You can then select one or more photos and delete them:

[image]

Comment: I see, but the delete button is disabled. And I can see is disabled in r picture as well.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Seems you can't delete pictures suitable as backgrounds/wallpapers (button stays disabled). And to make it even more interesting, the button turns black if you first select a wallpaper image and another one (which you can delete) afterwards.

Comment: I can't delete any of mine. Probably because I've imported them from the mac, and not just taken them from iPad or iPhone